# skipChangeCommits in Delta live table

Tags: databricks, autoload, delta-lake, scd, delta-live-tables

I am trying to create a DLT pipeline to implement SCD type 1. However, after my initial full refresh, when I am trying to do an incremental refresh, it fails giving below error:

"An error occurred because we detected an update or delete to one or more rows in the source table. Streaming tables may only use append-only streaming sources. If you expect to delete or update rows to the source table in the future, please convert table <> to a live table instead of a streaming live table. To resolve this issue, perform a Full Refresh to table <>. A Full Refresh will attempt to clear all data from table <> and then load all data from the streaming source. "

As per Databricks doc,

"By default, streaming tables require append-only sources. When a streaming table uses another streaming table as a source, and the source streaming table requires updates or deletes, for example, GDPR “right to be forgotten” processing, the skipChangeCommits flag can be set on the target streaming table to ignore those changes. "

But my doubt is autoloader anyways wont pick any changes to existing files and only new files being added would be picked unless we do an Full refresh of DLT pipeline. In that case what is the use of skipChangeCommits?

Can someone explain what is the exact use case for skipChangeCommits?

I tried setting skipChangeCOmmits to True in my streaming table but error is not resolve.

Comment: Since a stream is defined as append only, any stream read will fail if there is an update or delete to the source. A scenario can be if some old data has to be deleted or anonymized in case of GDPR or even if you have to delete old data which > retention period in the source. 
In all these cases, for your pipeline to succeed, it needs to ignore any deletes or updates to the source stream. This is exactly what skipChangeCommits is used for.  The other option is you do a full refresh. That is like re-starting from 0. But depending on the volume of data, that may not always be the great idea.

Comment: You said you tried setting skipChangeCOmmits  in your streaming table but you have not provided any code or screen shot or error message for anyone to assist you.  Please provide this information so folks can advise.